# Can I assign the result of an 'if' statement a variable automatically?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to figure out how to automatically determine how any page digits are in a book. I am very new to coding.
My current code looks like this

```
total_number_of_pages_in_the_book = 366

num_one_digit_pages = 9
num_two_digit_pages = 90
num_three_digit_pages = 900

digits_per_one_digit_page = 1
digits_per_two_digit_page = 2
digits_per_three_digit_page = 3

if total_number_of_pages_in_the_book > 9:
    print ("Number of one digit papers:", int(num_one_digit_pages))
if total_number_of_pages_in_the_book > 99:
    print ("Number of two digit papers:", int(num_two_digit_pages))
if total_number_of_pages_in_the_book < 999:
    print ("Number of three digit pages:", int(total_number_of_pages_in_the_book - num_two_digit_pages - num_one_digit_pages))
```

I need to make the the original statements of the number of digit pages now equal the result of the above if statements.

Not really sure what else to add. I tried a bunch of different things that were probably as dumb as the rest of my code.

Comment: when pasting code please press ctrl+k then put your code inside or atleast review how your question would look like(for now it looks like just random words put together in a paragraph) No one will be able to answer it unless it's clear code. check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What exactly is the desired output/result? It's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your page numbers are consecutive (no weird Roman numbering), you can use something like (formatted for readability):

```py
num_one_digit_pages = min(total_number_of_pages_in_the_book, 9)

num_two_digit_pages = 0 if num_one_digit_pages < 9 else 
    min(total_number_of_pages_in_the_book - 9, 90)

num_three_digit_pages = 0 if num_two_digit_pages < 90 else 
    min(total_number_of_pages_in_the_book - 99, 900)

num_other_digit_pages = 0 if num_three_digit_pages < 900 else 
    total_number_of_pages_in_the_book - 999
```

If you want to handle larger books, just add sections appropriately.

Or you could make it more generic with something like:

```py
def get_page_counts(num_pages):
    page_counts = []
    pages_left = num_pages
    pages_in_category = 9

    while pages_left > 0:
        page_counts.append(min(pages_left, pages_in_category))
        pages_left -= page_counts[-1]
        pages_in_category *= 10

    return page_counts

for test_val in (-1, 0, 1, 4, 9, 10, 366, 999, 1000, 1001, 123456):
    print(f"{test_val} -> {get_page_counts(test_val)}")
```

This generates a list of page counts for each digit quantity, such as per the output:

```py
-1 -> []
0 -> []
1 -> [1]
4 -> [4]
9 -> [9]
10 -> [9, 1]
366 -> [9, 90, 267]
999 -> [9, 90, 900]
1000 -> [9, 90, 900, 1]
1001 -> [9, 90, 900, 2]
123456 -> [9, 90, 900, 9000, 90000, 23457]
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
total_pages = 366

def calc_num_page(n):
    global total_pages
    total_pages -= n
    if total_pages >= 0:
        return n
    return total_pages + n

r = 0
for x, i in enumerate([calc_num_page((r := int('9' * (i+1)) - r)) for i in range(len(str(total_pages)))]):
    print(f"Number of {x+1}-digit papers: {i:,}")
```